# Modifying old Win32 application without source code (possibly written using Borland tools)

Tags: delphi, resources, c++builder, decompiling

I have a quite old Windows application (1998) which is no longer maintained by the author and I don't have its source code. This application in one of its windows has a dropdown list widget where the user can choose one of the 4 predefined values (numbers). I need to add new predefined values there or change the widget to something that lets me introduce any value (some edit field or editable combobox).

Some other data about the application:

- Probably written using some Borland tools, I guess it uses BDE and Paradox as its database.
- There is a file with `.mme` extension in the directory. I unpacked it and it contains 5 files: .data, .rdata, .rsrc, .sdata, .text. I viewed them in a hex editor and they contain some text data but I don't know how to look for those predefined values. Since they are numbers it's probable that I will find just some other numbers.

I tried using RedEdit and XN Resource Editor but they show only the icon and version info.

I know my question is kind of vague, but if I don't find any solution to this I will have to rewrite the whole program, so I'm asking just in case there is a solution.

Comment: Time to get another job if that's the level of assignment you get. I offer you my sympathy!

Comment: I agree with David. While it might be possible, the effort to produce this seems unreasonable. You might get lucky in that you "simply" need to patch in some extra values in whatever datastructure holds those widget values. Then again you might not.

Comment: It's not my job. A friend of my mother has this program and asked me for help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be possible to write another app that looks for this program, gets a handle to the window owning the drop-down box (if t's a native windows component), and then gets a handle to the drop-down box and use the Windows SendMessage API to manipulate the contents of the drop-down box.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632595(v=VS.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx

It might require so much effort that it may be better to just rewrite the app!

Comment: This is interesting. However, I'm afraid that Borland uses some kind of wrapper for Windows components (at least I think it was like that 12 years ago). I won't risk losing more time on this, I guess that offering to rewrite this program is the simplest solution. Thanks for all the answers anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If it is written with Borland tools, you can probably find out which one by searching the EXE for the string "Borland" - there should be a copyright string somewhere.

Once you know, find someone with Borland tools experience and have her find out if those numbers in the drop-down list happen to come out of a database table. If they do, try modifying that table, if not, rewrite the app :)

Comment: I've already checked all the database tables. Those values are written to one table but even if I change them manually they stay the same in the app.